# How to delete a range of values from an array?

Tags: ruby, arrays

If `array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`, 
I want to delete a range of elements from array.

For example: I want to delete all elements with an index in the range `2..5` from that array, the result should be `[1, 2, 7, 8, 9]`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 2..5 is the index range not values

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you really want to do? Remove values at indices 2..5, which is 2,3,4, and 5? or you want to remove those values which matches on or between 2..5?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use [`slice!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Array.html#method-i-slice-21):

> Deletes the element(s) given by [...] a range.

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
array.slice!(2..5)
array #=> [1, 2, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Yours is sweet and simple.  I almost forgot `slice!`

Comment: This should include `2` and not include `5`?

Comment: @Зелёный indices 2..5 refer to values 3, 4, 5 and 6.

Comment: Good solution, Stefan. I would be stunned [well and truely](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/well+and+truly) if the downvoter came forward to defend his/her black mark.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].reject.with_index{|element,index| index >= 2 && index <= 5}
=> [1, 2, 7, 8, 9]
```

or use `delete_if`

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].delete_if.with_index{|element,index| index >= 2 && index <= 5}
=> [1, 2, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

As Stefan posted, use `slice!` to remove values located inside a certain range in the array. If what you need, however, is to remove values that are within a certain range use `delete_if`.

```
array = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
array.delete_if {|value| (2..5) === value }
array  #=> [9, 8, 7, 6, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

### Delete When Range Includes Value

One of the many ways to do this is to invoke [Array#delete_if](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Array.html#method-i-delete_if) with a block that checks whether each element of the Array is included in the Range with [Array#include?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Array.html#method-i-include-3F). For example:

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
array.delete_if { |i| (2..5).include? i }
#=> [1, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Why post two separate answers? There is an "edit" link.

Answer (score -1):

### Delete Array Elements by Index from Range

If you are trying to delete elements by *index* rather than by value, one way to solve this is to iterate over your Range object, invoking [Array#delete_at](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Array.html#method-i-delete_at) for each index in the range. For example:

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
(2..5).map { |i| array.delete_at i }
##=> [3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Comment: Why post two separate answers? There is an "edit" link.

Comment: This does not work, array.delete_at is mutating the array while you are iterating.