# Remove multiple ranges of values from array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, range

```
a1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
a2 = [2..4, 8..11, 16..17]
```

Removing one range of values from an array can be done [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26909739/1417223):

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].slice!(2..5)
```

Iterating over the ranges and apply the same as above (`a2.each { |range| a1.slice!(range) }`) isn't perfect though. The ranges overlap sometimes and thus destroy the referencing index for the other ranges.

So, any suggestions on how to remove the ranges in `a2` from `a1` in the most efficient way? 
`a1` is normally [*0..10080] long. `a2` has about 30 ranges, each containing hundreds of values.

Comment: I imagine if the ranges are in sorted order you could reverse the array and start slicing from the back working forward?

Comment: Heh! :) I actually just came to think of that possibility, but then I realized that the ranges will sometimes overlap. So it's still not a good solution. See update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
a2 = [2..4, 8..11, 16..17]

a1 - a2.flat_map(&:to_a)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the result of the first operation impacts the second you're either going to have to track the resulting offset implications, which can get crazy complicated, or simply go about doing the reverse operation and instead flag which you want or don't want using the ranges:

```
require 'set'

a1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
a2 = [2..4, 8..11, 16..17]

# Convert the ranges to a set of index values to remove
reject = Set.new(a2.flat_map(&:to_a))

# Using value/index pairs, accumulate those values which are
# not being excluded by their index.
a1.each_with_index.each_with_object([ ]) do |(v, i), a|
  a << v unless (reject.include?(i))
end

# => [0, 1, 5, 6, 7, 12, 13, 14, 15, 18, 19, 20]
```

Comment: Excellent. But I assume the second part could be done like this equally well? `a1 - reject.to_a`

Comment: @FellowStranger Since `a1` contains values and not offsets, no, you can't do that. You'd have to convert the ranges to values, and that also presumes that the values are unique, which they may not be.

Comment: but it could be like this a1 - a2.flat_map(&:to_a)

Comment: @fanta Again, this presumes the values in `a1` are indicies and not random values.

Comment: This doesn't work in cases where `a1` doesn't start from 0. E.g. `a1 = [*10..20]`

Comment: It wasn't clear in your original example if you wanted values in `a1` excluded by their index or if you wanted them excluded by their *value*. If you want them excluded by value, it's really easy: `a1 - a2.flat_map(&:to_a)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the least naive solution, but it seems simple to convert your ranges into arrays so you're dealing with like-for-like:

```
a2.each{ |a| a1 = a1 - a.to_a }
```

Comment: `(a)` can be `a` here. Brackets are only necessary for raw ranges, like `(0..1).to-a`

Comment: So it can. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
[-1, *a2.flat_map(&:minmax), a1.length].each_slice(2).flat_map{|i,j| a1[i+1...j]}
# => [0, 1, 5, 6, 7, 12, 13, 14, 15, 18, 19, 20]
```