# How do I delete elements from an array at specified indexes, fi thsoe indexes are themselves in an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  If I have a group of array indexes, and I want to delete all the elements at those indexes, how do I do that?  I tried the below, but its leaving stuff out

```
2.4.0 :005 > indexes_to_delete = [7, 8, 9]
 => [7, 8, 9]

2.4.0 :008 > a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"]
 => ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"]
2.4.0 :009 > indexes_to_delete.each do |index| a.delete_at(index) end
 => [7, 8, 9]
2.4.0 :010 > a
 => ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "i"]
```

Notice the ending array.  I should have only seven elements in teh array since I started with ten and then specified three indexes of elements to delete in the array.  Yet I have eight elements.  How do I adjust my statement to delete the elements at the indexes I specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of ways to do that.

```
indexes_to_delete = [3, 8, 9]
a =    ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"]
```

**#1**

```
indexes_to_delete.sort.reverse_each { |i| a.delete_at(i) }
a #=>  ["a", "b", "c",      "e", "f", "g", "h"]
```

This mutates `a`. If that's not desired, operate on a copy of `a` (`a.dup`).

Just remember that you must delete the elements in the reverse order of their indexes.

**#2**

```
 a.values_at(*(0..a.size-1).to_a - indexes_to_delete)
   #=> ["a", "b", "c",      "e", "f", "g", "h"]
```

First we calculate the "keepers"

```
(0..a.size-1).to_a - indexes_to_delete 
  #=> [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
```

This does not mutate `a`. If `a` is to be mutated write

```
 a.replace(a.values_at(*(0..a.size-1).to_a - indexes_to_delete))
   #=> ["a", "b", "c",      "e", "f", "g", "h"] 
 a #=> ["a", "b", "c",      "e", "f", "g", "h"]
```

@maxple gives a third way (`reject.with_index`), which reads best to me. I doubt there are significant efficiency differences among the three.

Comment: A suggestion if I may, `0...a.size` instead of `0..a.size-1`.

Comment: @sagarpandya82, after having been bitten by 2 vs 3 dots a few times I decided to always use 2.

Answer (score 3):

Every time you delete an item from an array the indexes change.

So you could do this:

```
3.times { a.delete_at(7) }
```

Which has the same effect of deleting at 7,8,9

Or use `slice!` as recommended here: [How to delete a range of values from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26909447/how-to-delete-a-range-of-values-from-an-array)

```
a.slice!(7..9)
```

---

to work with arbitrary arrays, i think the obvious choice would be reject with index:

```
a.reject.with_index { |item, idx| indexes_to_delete.include? idx }
```

This is non-mutating so you'd set a variable equal to the result.

Comment: THe indexes aren't always going to be 7, 8, and 9 ... those are just examples I threw in to illustrate my point.  I'm looking for an answer that works with any array of numeric indexes (you can assume all the indexes reference valid elements in the array prior to any deletions).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the indexing changes when you do the delete.  So don't delete at first.

```
a = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"]
to_delete = [7,8,9]
to_delete.each { |i| a[i] = nil }
a.compact!
```

Set the elements you want to delete to nil, and then compact the array to get rid of those elements.

If you have nil elements you want to keep, but you have a value that you know would never have in the array, you could do

```
MARK = special value
to_delete.each { |i| a[i] = MARK }
a.delete(MARK)
```

Comment: This works as long as `a` contains no `nil` elements (that are to be kept).

Comment: Ugh, the curse of answering too quickly.